# #Flutter# One mode of implementing this modal pop-up (PresentViewController) is UIModalPresentationPageSheet

Tags: ios, flutter

One mode of implementing this modal pop-up (PresentViewController) is UIModalPresentationPageSheet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agAfK.png)

Does anyone know how to achieve this effect？

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.